# ActiveMQ transferExchange no longer working in Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm trying to upgrade the camel version of one of our applications. But it seems I can no longer send properties over ActiveMQ/JMS using the "transferExchange" option.

I wrote a small test program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
    context.addComponent("test-jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            String JMS_URI = "test-jms:queue:test.queue?transferExchange=true";

            from("direct:start")
                .setProperty("some-string", constant("foo"))
                .setProperty("some-date", body())
                .to(JMS_URI);

            from(JMS_URI)
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("some-string: " + exchange.getProperty("some-string"));
                        System.out.println("some-date: " + exchange.getProperty("some-date"));
                    }
                });
        }
    });

    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    context.start();
    template.sendBody("direct:start", new Date());

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    context.stop();
}
```

It outputs the correct values when using Camel 2.15.2 but nulls with 2.18.3.

How can I get the old behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exchange properties are not propagated anymore, and you cannot turn that on. Store your data in message headers.